# Check the fields in two objects in list

Tags: java, list, filter

I have list of objects:

```
{
  "rn": "14",
  "time": "2020-06-16 16:47:55",
  "id": 42332392988,
  "termname": "S1160AFB",
  "type": "100",
  "trancode": "110",
  "pan": "4790729949581839",
  "amount": "360.96",
  "approvalcode": "44444"
},
{
  "rn": "15",
  "time": "2020-06-16 16:48:55",
  "id": 42330308379,
  "termname": "S1160AFB",
  "type": "100",
  "trancode": "110",
  "pan": "4149510064617121",
  "amount": "360.96",
  "approvalcode": "55555"
},
{
  "rn": "13",
  "time": "2020-06-16 16:49:11",
  "id": 42332530886,
  "termname": "S1160AFB",
  "type": "420",
  "trancode": "110",
  "pan": "4790729949581839",
  "amount": "360.96",
  "approvalcode": "44444"
}
```

I need delete from list objects if :

1. they have the same field approvalcode. (approvalcode - unique. And can not be more than two identical)
2. Of two objects with the same approvalcode, you need to check the one in which the date is greater and and if in this object type = 420. Delete both objects from list.

I decided it like this:

1. I sort list by approvalcode and date.

   ```
    List<Transaction> filteredTrans = transResponse.getTransaction().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Transaction::approvalcode).thenComparing(Transaction::getTime))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```

After sorting, i compare the two closest objects.

```
  for (int i=0; i<filteredTrans.size()-1; i++) {
  if (filteredTrans.get(i).getApprovalcode().equals(filteredTrans.get(j).getApprovalcode()) && filteredTrans.get(j).getType().equals("420")) {
      filteredTrans.remove(i);
      filteredTrans.remove(j);
      j++;
  }
}
```

But I do not like the second part of the code. Can you please advise how it be improved?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a map instead of sorting. Here's how you can proceed with this

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {
  static class Transaction {
    String approvalCode;
    LocalDateTime time;
    int type;

    public Transaction(String approvalCode, LocalDateTime time, int type) {
      this.approvalCode = approvalCode;
      this.time = time;
      this.type = type;
    }

    public int getType() {
      return type;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getTime() {
      return time;
    }

    public String getApprovalCode() {
      return approvalCode;
    }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
          return "Transaction{" +
                  "approvalCode='" + approvalCode + '\'' +
                  ", time=" + time +
                  ", type=" + type +
                  '}';
      }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
    transactions.add(new Transaction("1", LocalDateTime.now(), 420));
    transactions.add(new Transaction("1", LocalDateTime.now(), 11));
    transactions.add(new Transaction("1", LocalDateTime.now(), 12));
    transactions.add(new Transaction("2", LocalDateTime.now(), 13));
    transactions.add(new Transaction("2", LocalDateTime.now(), 14));
    transactions.add(new Transaction("2", LocalDateTime.now(), 420));
    System.out.println(
        transactions.stream()
            .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                    Transaction::getApprovalCode,
                    Function.identity(),
                    (u, v) -> u.getTime().compareTo(v.getTime()) > 0 ? u : v))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .filter(v -> v.getType() != 420)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
  }
}
```

When iterating through a list, do not delete from the same list. It can lead to concurrent modification exception. Instead, copy all required elements to a new list/use stream filter

Comment: Thx for answer, but i need delete both objects if equals approvalCode and if in that where the date is greate type  = 420.
For example:
    List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
    transactions.add(new Transaction("1", LocalDateTime.now(), 420));
    transactions.add(new Transaction("1", LocalDateTime.now(), 12));
    transactions.add(new Transaction("2", LocalDateTime.now(), 13));

From this should stay Transaction with approvalCode == 2.

Comment: Result: [Transaction{approvalCode='1', time=2020-06-29T02:48:15.828, type=12}]

This will delete Transaction with approvalCode=2. Isn't this what you mean?

Comment: approvalCode=2 had to stay.Sorry if I poorly formulate the question

Comment: >2. Of two objects with the same approvalcode, you need to check the one in which the date is greater and and if in this object type = 420. Delete both objects from list.

Answered with the given conditions.

Comment: Yes, but object with the same approvalcode may be a maximum of 2. Sorry, Didn’t write it right away

Comment: The answer still remains the same. It does not matter if there are 2 or 100 objects with the same approvalcode. I can only help if you clearly define what is the expected output.

Comment: For example: List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>(); transactions.add(new Transaction("1", LocalDateTime.now(), 420)); transactions.add(new Transaction("1", LocalDateTime.now(), 12)); transactions.add(new Transaction("2", LocalDateTime.now(), 13)); 

From this should stay 1 object where Transaction with approvalCode == 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216893/discussion-between-palash-goel-and-lukas).

Answer (score 0):

Thx for help all.
This code help me:

```
List<Transaction> filteredTrans = transResponse.getTransaction().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Transaction::getApprovalcode))
    .values()
    .stream()
    .filter(l -> {
        if (l.size() == 1) return true;
        Transaction maxTimeTr = l.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Transaction::getTime)).orElseThrow();
        return !maxTimeTr.getType().equals("420");
    })
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```